# Retrofit 1.9 with Proguard

Tags: retrofit, android-proguard

I am using following libs in my project -

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
```

But when I am using Proguard, my app crashes with following error

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: d.a: Last parameter must be of type Callback<X> or Callback<? super X>.
           at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(Unknown Source)
           at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(Unknown Source)
           at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.(Unknown Source)
           at retrofit.RestAdapter.create(Unknown Source)
           at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
           at $Proxy2.a(Unknown Source)
           at in.wishup.assistant.activities.SplashActivity.fetchOneTouchDetails(Unknown Source)
           at in.wishup.assistant.activities.SplashActivity$1.done(Unknown Source)
           at in.wishup.assistant.activities.SplashActivity$1.done(Unknown Source)
           at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(Unknown Source)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I think Retrofit's Asynchronus calls doesn't work with Proguard. Has anybody faced similiar issue? I tried many links but nothing worked.

```
##proguard-rules.pro##

-keep class com.google.android.gms.* { *; } <br>  -keep class * extends android.app.Activity  <br>  -keepclassmembers class ** { <br>
     @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;<br>
     @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;<br>  }<br>  -keepnames class com.levelup.http.okhttp.** { *; }<br>  -keepnames interface com.levelup.http.okhttp.** { *; }<br>  -keepnames class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }<br>  -keepnames interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }<br>

 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.*<br>
 -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement<br>

 -keepattributes Signature<br>
 -keepattributes *Annotation*<br>

 -dontwarn rx.**<br>
 -keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }<br>
 -keep class com.google.inject.* { *; }<br>
 -keep class org.apache.http.* { *; }<br>
 -keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.* { *; }<br>
 -keep class javax.inject.* { *; }<br>
 -keep class retrofit.* { *; }<br>
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }<br>
 -keep class in.wishup.assistant.testobfuscation.** { *; }<br>  -keep class retrofit.** { *; }<br>  -keepclasseswithmembers class * {<br>
     @retrofit.http.* <methods>;<br>  }<br>

 -keep class com.parse.* { *; }<br>  -dontwarn com.parse.*<br>

 -dontwarn retrofit.appengine.**<br>

 -keep class com.package.name.models.** { *; }<br>  -keepclassmembers class com.package.name.models.** { *; } <br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-square-retrofit.pro

> If in your rest service interface you use methods with Callback
>   argument.
>
> ```
> -keepattributes Exceptions
> ```